# Webpack style-loader vs mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: webpack, thymeleaf, webpack-style-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

**Update**
After writing these sentences I gave myself the answer. With `style-loader` i do not need to build first, i can even checkout my repository and start webpack-dev-server. Is this correct?

However, second question is remaining.

---

I've got a Spring-Boot Application using thymeleaf and webpack.

In my `startpage.html` I'm including a stylesheet by link tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/startpage.css}"/>
   </head>
   ...
   <script th:src="@{/js/startpage.js}"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to improve the app and therefore I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Colt/webpack-demo-app). I've divided my webpack.config file into a dev and prod part. 
Dev part is using `webpack style-loader`, prod is using `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

**webpack.dev.config**

```
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**webpack.prod.config**

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /printView\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "css/[name].css"
    })
  ]
```

I already know what those tools are doing. With the help of `style-loader` i could import my css through my js file:

**startpage.js**

```
import "../css/startpage.scss";
```

Therefore I do not need to write the link-tag `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/startpage.css}"/>` explicitly in my html.
However, I've got a huge css file and everytime I reload my side during development-mode for a short period of time there my html is unstyled which causes the following [problem](https://youtu.be/MpGLUVbqoYQ?t=5725) (html is unstyled for short period of time).

Now I'm asking why i should even use the `style-loader` and not just go up with inserting a `link` tag and use `mini-css-extract-plugin`? Whats the advantage?

Secondly, I'm asking if I could  load  the styles produced by `style-loader` even faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing these sentences I gave myself the answer. With style-loader i do not need to build first, i can even checkout my repository and start webpack-dev-server.

Edit: Some useful [link](https://maxrozen.com/difference-between-style-loader-mini-css-extract-plugin)